# How to fix Android application that got rejected by google play store due to Eligibility Issue?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console

I got an email from google play stating:

> Publishing status: Rejected
>
> After review, your app has been rejected
> and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an
> update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google
> Play. Reasons of violation     Issue: Violation of Families Policy
> Requirements Apps that target children must comply with all Families
> Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:
>
> Eligibility Issue: Designed for Families eligibility
>
> After careful
> consideration, we have determined that your app does not meet our
> eligibility criteria for the Designed for Families program. Apps in
> the program must be specifically designed for children or families,
> have a rating of E or E10+, and include relevant app information. Here
> are some examples of common apps that are ineligible for the program:
>
> Apps that are rated ESRB Everyone but contain ads for gambling or any
> inappropriate content Apps for parents or care-givers (e.g.,
> breastfeeding tracker, developmental guide) Parent guides or device
> management apps that are only intended for use by parents or
> care-givers

I have made privacy policy for my app and it contains ads from admob and I have blocked all sensitive ads.
Target audience is set to 9-12 and 13+.
Why my app is getting rejected?

Comment: Why exactly is hard to tell. Could be anything vaguely mentioned in the reason / policy (which is really long). But "can be used by children also" and "Apps in the program must be specifically designed for children" is something different. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9285070 "primarily for kids < 13" vs "everyone including children". You seem to have chosen to make it specifically for children, maybe you should go the other route? A dictionary doesn't sound like a kids only app.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help],

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to update your **target audience** and **Content**, Maybe Your app's content that is accessible to children must be appropriate for children, know more pls [click here](https://play.google.com/about/families/children-and-families/families-policy/)

Comment: My app is an English Dictionary - Offline application for android that can be used by children's also

Comment: You have to update your contain rating go to - play store console - > Store Presence - > Content Rating

Comment: Content rating is 3+

Comment: Have you changed your target audience?

Answer (score 4):

**Apps with unintentional appeal to children**.

We want to make sure that apps with a content rating below T that are not designed for children don't inadvertently attract them.

If your app is not designed for children but your listing contains marketing elements that may appeal to them (such as youthful animation or young characters in the graphic assets), choose Yes. This is not an acknowledgement that your app appeals to children, but is your consent to apply a banner to your store listing that says “Not designed for children.” This helps parents know that your app is not designed for children.

If your app is not designed for children and you believe that your store listing does not contain any marketing elements that may appeal to children OR if you’re unsure, select No. No special designation will appear in your store listing.

Answer (score 1):

If your application contains ads, then I suggest:

- Under App content
- You should check the "Yes, my store listing could appeal to children"
  [image: app content for store listing]